# Unable to add record into multiple publication lists using SSJS script Activity in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, insert, debug, publicationlist

Am trying to insert records into many publication lists from a DE(say XXX - this DE has emailaddress, subscriberkey, listid, list name, status) using SSJS. But no output is coming.

Please review my below code. Let me know where am wrong. Also is there a way to debug SSJS scripts. Am new to SSJS.

```javascript
<script runat ="server">
 Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");
     var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    
 var MemberDE = DataExtension.Init("XXX");
  var DERows = MemberDE.Rows.Retrieve();
 
  for (var i in DERows)
  
  {
  
 var email_id = DERows[i].EmailAddress;
 var sub_key = DERows[i].SubscriberKey;
 var list_id = DERows[i].ListId;
 var list_name = DERows[i].ListName;
 var status1 = DERows[i].Status;
  var options = {SaveOptions: [{'PropertyName': '*', SaveAction: 'UpdateAdd'}]};
   
        
         var sub = { 
          SubscriberKey: sub_key, 
          EmailAddress: email_id,
          Lists: [{
            ID: list_id,
            Status: status1
          }]
        };
        
         var data = prox.createItem("Subscriber", sub, options);
     
  
     Write(data.Results[0].StatusCode);
  }

      </script>
```

Comment: For debugging purpose, you could use try catch statements within your code

Comment: ok @SwatiMishra